# Focus Trap React and a few component's in 2 popup's

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, modal-dialog, focus

I have 2 popup's(**I reuse** **CloseButton**(component) and **Modal**(component) **in 2 popup's**) and need to do focus trap at all. I lf answer 4 better way.

1. [1 popup Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ZdVc.png), components: ModalLogin-**Modal**-**CloseButton**.

I read about some hooks: *useRef()* and *forwardRef(props, ref)*
but i don't undestand why it's not work in my case. I am trying to find a solution.  I need help :)

In ModalLogin, I try to do a focus trap. To do this, I mark what should happen with focus when moving to 1 and the last element. I need to pass my ref hook obtained via Modal-CloseButton. I read that you can't just transfer refs to functional components. I try to use the forwardref hook in the necessary components where I transfer it, here's what I do:

All links without focus-trap and hook's!.

https://github.com/j3n4r3v/ligabank-credit/blob/master/src/components/form-login/modal-login.jsx [Modal-login full]

```js
    const ModalLogin = () => {
        const topTabTrap* = useRef();
        const bottomTabTrap* = useRef();
        const firstFocusableElement = useRef();
        const lastFocusableElement = useRef();
    
    useEffect(() => {
         const trapFocus = (event) => {
            if (event.target === topTabTrap.current) {
                lastFocusableElement.current.focus()
            }
            if (event.target === bottomTabTrap.current) {
                firstFocusableElement.current.focus()
            }
        }
        document.addEventListener('focusin', trapFocus)
        return () => document.removeEventListener('focusin', trapFocus)
      }, [firstFocusableElement, lastFocusableElement])
    
      return ( 
            <Modal onCloseModal={() => onCloseForm()} ref={lastFocusableElement}>
    
            <form >
                <span ref={topTabTrap} tabIndex="0" />
                    <Logo />
                    <Input id="email" ref={firstFocusableElement} />
                    <Input id="password" />
                    <Button type="submit" />
                <span ref={bottomTabTrap} tabIndex="0"/>
            </form>
    
        </Modal>
    );
    };
```

https://github.com/j3n4r3v/ligabank-credit/blob/master/src/components/modal/modal.jsx [Modal full]

```js
const Modal = forwardRef(({ props, ref }) => {
      const { children, onCloseModal, ...props } = props;
      const overlayRef = useRef();
      useEffect(() => {
        const preventWheelScroll = (evt) => evt.preventDefault();
            document.addEventListener('keydown', onEscClick);
            window.addEventListener('wheel', preventWheelScroll, { passive: false });
        return () => {
            document.removeEventListener('keydown', onEscClick);
            window.removeEventListener('wheel', preventWheelScroll);
        };
    });
    const onCloseModalButtonClick = () => {
        onCloseModal();
    };

    return (
        <div className="overlay" ref={overlayRef}
            onClick={(evt) => onOverlayClick(evt)}>
            <div className="modal">
                <CloseButton
                    ref={ref}
                    onClick={() => onCloseModalButtonClick()}
                    {...props}
                />
                    {children}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
    });
```

https://github.com/j3n4r3v/ligabank-credit/blob/master/src/components/close-button/close-button.jsx [CloseButton full]

```js
const CloseButton = forwardRef(({ props, ref }) => {
        const {className, onClick, ...props} = props;
     return (
        <button className={`${className} close-button`}
            onClick={(evt) => onClick(evt)}
            tabIndex="0"
            ref={ref}
                {...props}
            >Close</button>
    );
    });
```

And now i have a lot of errors just like: 1 - Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'children') - Modal, 2 - ... className undefined in CloseButton etc.

2. [2 popup Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ve2wC.png), components: **Modal**(reuse in 1 popup) - InfoSuccess- **CloseButton**(reuse in 1 popup)

I have only 1 interactive element - button (tabindex) and no more. Now i don't have any idea about 2 popup with focus-trap ((

https://github.com/j3n4r3v/ligabank-credit/blob/master/src/components/success-modal/success-modal.jsx [SuccessModal  full]

```js
    const SuccessModal = ({ className, onChangeVisibleSuccess }) => {
    return (
        <Modal onCloseModal={() => onChangeVisibleSuccess(false)}>
            <InfoSuccess className={className} />
         </Modal>
    );
};
```

https://github.com/j3n4r3v/ligabank-credit/blob/master/src/components/info-block/info-block.jsx [Infoblock full]

```js
    const InfoBlock = ({ className, title, desc, type }) => {
    return (
        <section className={`info-block ${className} info-block--${type}`}>
            <h3 className="info-block__title">{title}</h3>
            <p className="info-block__desc">{desc}</p>
        </section>
    );
};

     const InfoSuccess = ({ className }) => (
       <InfoBlock
         title="Спасибо за обращение в наш банк."
         desc="Наш менеджер скоро свяжется с вами по указанному номеру телефона."
         type="center"
         className={className}
    />
);
```

I know about 3 in 1 = 1 component and no problem in popup with Focus-Trap. But i want understand about my case, it's real to life or not and what best practice.